# Symfony 2.2 create form through a service

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

i in Symfony 2.2 i want to create a little contact form through a service. I played around with the service configuration and the form components factories but everytime i got the following exception:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Form\Form::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Form\FormConfigInterface, string given


parameters:
  anchorbrands_common.contact.form.type.class: Anchorbrands\Bundle\CommonBundle\Form\Type\ContactFormType
  anchorbrands_common.contact.form.name: anchorbrands_commonbundle_contactformtype

services:
  anchorbrands_common.footer.contact.form:
    class: Symfony\Component\Form\Form
    factory-method: createNamed
    factory-service: form.factory
    arguments: ["%anchorbrands_common.contact.form.type.class%", "null"]

  anchorbrands_common.footer.contact.form.type:
    class: %anchorbrands_common.contact.form.type.class%
    arguments: ["null"]
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: %anchorbrands_common.contact.form.name% }
```

Would be nice if someone can give me some advice, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem due to misspelling:

- `factory-method` and `factory-service` are wrong, `factory_method` and `factory_service` are correct.

I'm not sure you can use a `%parameter%` as an `alias` for your `form.type` tag:

- if you still have a concern, try to put a raw string instead (`anchorbrands_commonbundle_contactformtype` in your case).

An argument is missing in your `anchorbrands_common.footer.contact.form` service and the first one seems to be wrong:

- please try : `[anchorbrands_commonbundle_contactformtype, anchorbrands_commonbundle_contactformtype, null]` (the form name and the alias for the form type can be the same)
- if it works, then try with the `%anchorbrands_common.contact.form.name%` equivalent parameter.

I hope this can help you.

References: [Define a Symfony 2 Form as a Service](http://www.webtipblog.com/define-a-symfony-2-form-as-a-service/)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you surround your arguments with double quotas?

Try to change (where you don't need a string, but i suppose that you don't need a string at all) arguments passage in that way:

```
services:
  anchorbrands_common.footer.contact.form:
    class: Symfony\Component\Form\Form
    factory-method: createNamed
    factory-service: form.factory
    arguments: [%anchorbrands_common.contact.form.type.class%, null]

  anchorbrands_common.footer.contact.form.type:
    class: %anchorbrands_common.contact.form.type.class%
    arguments: [null]
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: %anchorbrands_common.contact.form.name% }
```

### Remember

Error reporting is important and you should read them carefully because them could help you a lot

Comment: Thank you for answering me!
I used the quotes cause it was described in the documentation:
http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/service_container.html

services:
    newsletter_manager:
        class:     "%newsletter_manager.class%"
        arguments: ["@mailer", "@templating"]

nevermind.. it still doesnt work and says a string is given :(

Comment: @user1987373: again, you're doing something wrong. Why do you surround `@mailer` and `@templating` with double quotas?

Comment: cause it is described in the Documentation as you can see here!!! 

symfony.com/doc/master/book/service_container.html


but as i said, i still got the exception also without the quotes

Comment: @user1987373: that's because it need a string as input! Error is talking to you and said: you should pass me an object but you're passing me a string. Ok, where you pass a string?

Comment: i dont get it. I pass %anchorbrands_common.contact.form.type.class% as the argument which is the form type Anchorbrands\Bundle\CommonBundle\Form\Type\ContactFormType, why does the factory interpret it as a string?

Comment: @user1987373: because you sorrund it with double quotas! why don't you get it ? However, I suppose that error is here, because you paste this snippet of code, but could be elsewhere. Moreover, if you don't surrond it with double quotas, what error you get?

Comment: as i said i get the same error with AND without double quotes :)

as you can see here: http://pastebin.com/Tnsthueg

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28820/discussion-between-user1987373-and-doncallisto)